Logic help: I want to support multiple icons in a container C++/QML
I have a C++ Qt application with a top row container consisting of 9 icon positions. Each icon position currently has an icon source (URL), a bool for toggled on/off, and an icon state that changes color and other properties. I need to enhance this functionality by allowing each icon position to support multiple layered SVGs, where each layer can change color, appear, or disappear independently, but still be represented within a single icon position.
Current Implementation:
Icon Interface: Provides getters and setters for source, priority, position, and state.
IconPosition: Contains QProperties for source, toggleOnOff, and state of the current icon in that position. This class manages which icon is active based on priorities.
IconPresenter: Connects an icon to its position.
IconContainer.qml: Uses properties passed from IconPosition and acts as a container for a single icon with various states.
I now need to extend the functionality to support an icon that has multiple SVG layers. Each layer should be capable of independently changing color, appearing, or disappearing. Additionally, these layered icons should still be manageable within the existing IconPosition structure. What should I do?
What I've Tried
Combining SVGs: I've attempted to combine multiple SVGs into one using a method that reads and combines SVG content, then converts it into a Base64-encoded data URL for use in QML. However, I'm now thinking this isn't possible.

I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. If you create your "average" SVG, you'll end up with only one icon to draw so it's no different from the "single layer" thing.

I don't see why you need multiple .svg files. MultiEffects should enable you to recolor your icons (provided they're coded using 'white' as their color), and a visibility flag should suffice. Do you need a particular position to support multiple icons, or just variations on color and visibility?

Assuming that by "layers" you mean SVG groups, I sincerely doubt that you can do anything you want directly from QML. I believe that the only option is to implement this on the C++ side with a custom type that eventually implement painting on its own using QSvgRenderer. It may be possible to achieve something with multiple SVG, each one assigned to a different Icon (or Image?) and set as children of a top level element, all shown as stacked (exactly like layers should be), but that's just a thought, I don't have enough experience with QML.

Since it's a SVG question, I want to draw you attention to:

SVG data-uri notation
Javascript backtick notation

supports multiline string literals
string interpolation for expanding property bound values



Combined, we can create dynamic changing SVG where each element can change their color including going transparent
Image {
    source: `data:svg+xml,
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="8" stroke="${circleColor.currentText}" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
<path stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="${tickColor.currentText}" d="M 16 12 L 14 10 L 14 2 L 18 2 L 18 10 z" />
<path stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="${tickColor.currentText}" d="M 20 16 L 22 14 L 30 14 L 30 18 L 22 18 z"/>
<path stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="${tickColor.currentText}" d="M 16 20 L 18 22 L 18 30 L 14 30 L 14 22 z "/>
<path stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="${tickColor.currentText}" d="M 12 16 L 10 18 L 2 18 L 2 14 L 10 14 z"/>
</svg>
`
    sourceSize: Qt.size(64, 64)
}
ComboBox {
    id: circleColor
    model: ["red", "green", "blue", "transparent"]
}
ComboBox {
    id: tickColor
    model: ["blue", "green", "red", "transparent"]
}

You can Try it Online!
If your icons themselves, come from a data model, string interpolation may not be an option, but, you could consider arg notation instead, i.e.
Image {
    source: `data:svg+xml,
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="8" stroke="%1" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
<path stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="%2" d="M 16 12 L 14 10 L 14 2 L 18 2 L 18 10 z" />
<path stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="%2" d="M 20 16 L 22 14 L 30 14 L 30 18 L 22 18 z"/>
<path stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="%2" d="M 16 20 L 18 22 L 18 30 L 14 30 L 14 22 z "/>
<path stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="%2" d="M 12 16 L 10 18 L 2 18 L 2 14 L 10 14 z"/>
</svg>
`.arg(circleColor.currentText).arg(tickColor.currentText)
    sourceSize: Qt.size(64, 64)
}

